# Strange linkers and them not working with intellisense

Tags: vba, ms-access

All the docs about how to reference a form inside of a navigation form kept giving me odd code.  VBA code using [ ] and !.  I finally understand that the following code:

```
[Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![cboCnty1]
```

was what I needed to resolve my issue.  What I don't understand is why.  It's so alien from everything else VBA that I know. It doesn't work with Intellisense either, which just made the journey to the right answer look like I was going the wrong way.

Why isn't it something more like:

```
Forms(NavigationForm).Controls("NavigationSubform").Controls("cboCnty1")
```

Ok, bad example, I know.  But

```
Me.cboCnty1
```

would work find if the code wasn't in a module.  I'm simply looking for greater understanding.

Comment: This should work: `Forms("NavigationForm").Controls("NavigationSubform").Form.Controls("cboCnty1")`

Comment: The `Me` in `Me.cboCnty1` refers to the class that the code is running in. If this code was run outside the class, it would either fail or find the wrong `cboCnty1`

Comment: Intellisense doesn't work with any of these examples (except for `Me.cboCnty1`). The `!` means the references are late bound (Intellisense only works with early bound object references). A partial early-bound reference that will work (in NavigationForm): `Me.NavigationSubform.Form![cboCnty1]`. The `![cboCnty1]` is late bound because the subform's `Form` property returns a generic form, not the specific form contained in the subform.

Comment: Thank you. I have more to learn about early & late bound, but I understand how to reference the control now. Will I be a weaker programmer for favoring the ( ) notation over [ ]? I would like to use your 1st example.

Comment: Both the `()` and `[]` are late bound. In fact, you could say that `[]` calls get translated to the `()` syntax at runtime. The most important use of early bound references is catching more errors earlier: `Form_MyForm.Control` will be checked at compile time, while [Forms]![MyForm]![Control] will fail at runtime. Early-bound also runs faster, but this is only really noticible in loops. You are a stronger programmer when you know the difference between the two reference types, and when to use them.